# Modifying devise mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-4, actionmailer, devise-confirmable

I'm using devise for authentication in my app. When  a user signs up a confirmation email is sent to the user which says

```
Welcome user@gmail.com !

You can confirm your account email through the link below:

Confirm my account
```

But I want to display user's name instead of email. How can I implement this? PLease help. I have devise viewws with me. But it uses an `@email` instance variable to display email. Where is it defined? Help would be appreciated.

```
<p>Welcome <%= @email %>!</p>

<p>You can confirm your account email through the link below:</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Confirm my account', confirmation_url(@resource, :confirmation_token => @token) %></p>
```

Comment: Its not the duplicate of that question, I have devise views in my application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@resource` is likely to be your user.

So replace `@email` (defined in the devise mailer) with `@resource.name` (or whatever method you use to get the name)